# I get the error while trying to modify the value in the xml tag

Tags: xml, ant

XML Which i want to change the tag **DOMAIN** value from `111.111.111.111` to `222.222.222.222`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!--
    Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
    5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
    US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
-->
<wl:adapter xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration" xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="maximo">
    <!--This adapter has been upgraded, For more information about the changes, see the "Adapter timeout and concurrency" topic in the product Knowledge Center.-->
    <displayName>maximo</displayName>
    <description>maximo</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>111.111.111.111</domain>
            <port>80</port> 
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
            <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
            <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
            -->     
        <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <!--The previous elements: <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds> and <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>, were added to <connectionPolicy> element. These elements correspond to TCP connection and socket timeouts when connecting to the back-end. For more details, see HTTP protocol specifications and "Adapter timeout and concurrency" topic in the product Knowledge Center.-->
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>2</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
            <!--The <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode> element has been moved from <loadConstraint> element (and loadConstraint has been commented out). This element sets the maximum number of concurrent requests to the backend. For more information, see the "Adapter timeout and concurrency" topic in the product Knowledge Center.-->
        </connectionPolicy>
        <!--<loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />-->
    </connectivity>
        <!-- Service Request -->
    <procedure name="getFree"/>
    <procedure name="getFreee"/>

</wl:adapter>
```

Ant Build File build.xml file

```
<project>
    <property environment="env" />
    <property file="project.properties"/>
    <xmltask source="C:\IBMMF63\Rought\maximo.xml" dest="C:\IBMMF63\Rought\maximo.xml">
        <replace path="wl:adapter/connectivity/domain[text()]" withText="${adapter.ip}" />
    </xmltask>

    <target name="build" >

      <exec executable="C:\IBMMF63\Rought\arg.bat">
        <arg value="${java.home}" />
        <redirector output="Log.txt" alwayslog="true"/>   

      </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

I am new to ant Script if i am wrong correct me.

Error i get while executing the build.xml file

```
Buildfile: ....\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
....\build.xml:4: Problem: failed to create task or type xmltask
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson same error

Comment: Sorry, meant to type `wl:adapter/connectivity/connectionPolicy/domain/text()`, however I'm not sure how namespaces are resolved in xmltasks so may be totally off.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thank a lot i used another way to change it :)

Answer (score 0):

The [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/index.html) is an ant addon that needs the [xmltask.jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmltask/files/xmltask/1.16/xmltask.jar/download) on ant path, then use [ant taskdef task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html) to bring it into the game:

```
<project>

 <!-- Import XMLTask -->
 <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>

 [...]

</project>
```